# java audio frequency filter

Tags: java, audio, frequency

I'm developing a simple audio player in java. The only advanced feature I need is a frequency filter. It's not necessarily a full-featured equalizer function, with different gains for specific frequency ranges: a low pass filter which cuts frequencies higher than a specified value would be enough.

I studied [jlGui](http://www.javazoom.net/jlgui/jlgui.html) which has an equalizer, but it only works with MP3 data, while the files I will be playing are OGG.

Browsing through various answers I found that an ffmpeg wrapper like [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) or [Jave](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/index.php?lang=en) could be a solution. But I didn't find any tutorial, not even a starting point on how to handle frequency filtering with ffmpeg.

Also JMF is described as a valid choice for implementing such a function, but I found nothing specific enough.

Comment: If you have PCM audio data, you could implement your own filter. Though this is a task usually performed by engineers, you could use a "cookbook" resource, such as this http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt or this http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Audio-Java-Craig-Lindley/dp/0130876763

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~kvdoel/jass/doc/index.html

This is the JavaDoc for the JASS project by UBC Vancouver. It's free for non-commercial use. You should be able to implement most kinds of filters with it. Check the URL few levels up for actual source download.

Comment: Thanks. I've spent a few hours analyzing this interesting project but, for what I could understand, it only provides filtering for the frequency components of the sound it dinamically generates. I wasn't able to apply the same filters to loaded audio files. I would be happy to be proven wrong, but it looks like JASS is not what I need.

Comment: I have used this in practice projects which perform filtering on PCM data. It works very well...Especially the BiQuad filters which are pretty straightforward to implement on your own anyway. Here are some more links to help you : http://www.arachnoid.com/BiQuadDesigner/index.html --- This site is pretty useful to get the coefficients for your BiQuad. ...and also : http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt ... Since you want to make an EQ. I have used the content at both sites in code at times , and it works very well in practice too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm ending up using this solution (for windows applications) : [Equalizer APO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/)

It makes use of the Audio Processing Object technology available on Windows Vista and later. My application just needs to edit a configuration text file and the APO does the rest.

Obviously, it is platform dependent, and I must install an external application for my filter to work, but it is acceptable in my case, and it is very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I found an old project called [JEQ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jeq/)
It is based on javax.sound and uses [IIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response) to create a 10/15/25/31-band equalizer. It works on PCM data (not just MP3 like others) so I hope I can make it work with OGG. My only concerns are about output quality, which wasn't very good in some of my tests. I'll have to investigate